# How can I remove Ubuntu and reinstall a fresh Ubuntu 15.04 to my computer?

Tags: system-installation, uninstall, system, 15.04

I don't really know what I'm doing, and don't want to get this wrong.

I've made a backup of everything I want to keep on an external hard drive, and wish to do a clean install of Ubuntu 15.04 from a completely ghosted system. I do not have a partition, I only have the Ubuntu OS.

Does anyone have any information regarding what I must do?

I have no problem removing everything off my computer and restarting from scratch. I cannot update to newer kernels due to various issues and I am having a few other problems with my computer that I would rather just reinstall instead of fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Ubuntu is going to be the only OS on your machine, then you're kind of ready already.

Download the correct version of the 15.04 installation .iso file from the Ubuntu downloads page, bearing in mind whether you have a 64bit or 32bit machine. The installer will need to be burnt onto a dvd, or a bootable usb (slightly trickier, but by no means difficult).

You will need to make your BIOS boot from the installation DVD, right at the beginning of your boot process, you'll need to press something like <kbd>Del</kbd> to choose your boot media, though this info will flash on screen quickly.

When installing, choose the option to install Ubuntu as your main OS, this will remove any other OS. If you have a particular partition setup in mind, select manual partitioning when you reach that option, but the automatic partitioning works well for most users.

Just remember, so long as you have your files backed up, you can always start again with the installation process so be brave! Good luck!

Comment: What's tricky about creating a boot stick with the Startup Disk Creater tool installed in Ubuntu?